# Add Easing effect within Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can anyone help me intergrate an easing effect within my Accordion?

What I want is to mimic this effect (which can be set in your CSS) with JQuery:

```
  -webkit-transition: max-height 500ms ease, padding 500ms ease;
  transition: max-height 500ms ease, padding 500ms ease;
```

How can I accomplish this?

Made a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1somnqjz/) of my problem.

***PS. Having a smooth easing effect would also do the trick.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to replicate what **`slideDown()`** and **`slideUp()`** of jQuery by doing them in pure CSS with the use of **`transition`** property.

Then try **[this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/w3qdoo2u/)** out.

***CSS:***

```
h3 {
    display: block;
    background-color: pink;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.accordion__content {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 300ms ease-in-out, padding 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.accordion__content--displayed {
    max-height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

***JavaScript:***

```
$(function () {
    $('.accordion h3').click(function () {
        $(this).next('.accordion__content').toggleClass('accordion__content--displayed');
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: doh! it seems I misunderstood the question. You want to replicate *CSS* with jQuery and not the other way around as I had thought.

Comment: No!! This is perfect. Easy JQuery code and the desired effect. Thank you!:)

Answer (score 1):

By default, jQuery's `slideUp()` provides 2 easing functions -

- swing (default)
- linear

There are many more easing functions available but as external plugins.

As of now, if you want a smooth easing effect, you can change the speed in `milliseconds` like this -

```
$(this).next(".accordion__content").slideToggle(500).siblings(".pane:visible").slideUp();
```

Check this [**link**](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/), jQuery UI provides many easing functions